# Use javascript to control some html fields of a form before submitting

Tags: javascript, php

Before submitting a form, i use javascript code (surrounded in PHP) in order to make locally some controls but sometimes javascript may not be enabled client-side.

The fact is that I have to check by pattern/regex each control of the form for example checking email, phone number,.. format so that user cannot enter anything haphazardly. Therefore, if javascript is not enabled, the form must not be submitted, even if all field are fulfilled out.

Therefore my question is to know if there is a tag or function which allow to perform what i want to?
Thank for your help

Comment: Let me make sure I'm clear on your question, if the user has JavaScript disabled, you want to enable it against their will?

Comment: You cannot enable JS in a user's browser (thank god!). They have to do that themselves

Comment: Which navigator? Not Netscape, is it?

Comment: Excuse me for misunderstanding! The fact is that I have to check by pattern/regex each control of the form for example checking email, phone number,.. format so that user cannot enter anything haphazardly.I use Chrome/firefox/IE. Thank you very much

Comment: Then they sacrifice the convenience of browser side checks by having JS disabled, which is their choice. The best you can do is use that regex on server side to make sure it's valid.

Comment: yes, it's more clear now. thank you very much for your attention and good help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript runs client-side.

That means that users have **FULL CONTROL** over it.

Then, if they want to disable it, you can't do anything about it.

The only thing you should do is be sure that users with JS disabled will be able to submit the form too.

---

If you use JS to validate the form, be aware that users have **FULL CONTROL** over it, so they can send the form if they want, even if your code says that it's invalid.

The right way to do it is:

- Be sure users without javascript can send the form
- Implement client-side validation for users with javascript activation. This way they will have a better user experience (because can know if the data is invalid immediately) and is less server intensive (your server will have to validate less invalid forms).
- **ALWAYS** validate the submited form server-side. Data coming from a client is always **UNTRUSTED**, even if you think you have validated it.

Comment: Excuse me for misunderstanding! The fact is that I have to check by pattern/regex each control of the form for example checking email, phone number,.. format so that user cannot enter anything haphazardly.Thanks

Comment: thank you my friend. This is much clearer for me now. Thank you for your attention and your patience